# unresolved import 'django.utils'

Tags: python, base-de-datos, django

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto de escuela, y a la hora de pasar el código de la pc de la escuela a la pc de mi casa me lanza este error:

> unresolved import 'django.utils'

¿Alguna idea?

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
```

Ya he descargado django desde comando pip, pero me sigue lanzando el mismo error.

Answer (score 0):

Ese error te dice que no encuentra Django, puedes verificarlo con un `pip list`

Te recomiendo buscar info sobre virtualenv y virtualenvwrapper